# in-app Purchase signed apk not working

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I am working in  in-app purchase application. 
The .apk , which is uploaded in play-store is not working properly in device. 
But the .apk created from my Studio is working fine.

I am not able to understand on this different behaviour of the same piece of code.
Please suggest to overcome from this issue.

Comment: have you used proguard to generate signed APK?? AND BEFORE UPLOAD APP ON PLAY HAVE YOU TESTED SAME APK IN YOUR DEVICE??

Comment: Yes .. the code is same. Still I have the same code in my Android Studio, which is working fine

Comment: Can you provide more details like which part of your application is not working..